# Checkboxes showing on the backend, but not on the frontend?

Tags: front-end

I've gone through all of the "Q's and A's" on the forum, however have not found a suitable solution yet. I've created numerous forms on WP Forms, and have important "checkboxes" that are required elements of my forms.

Everything is working perfectly well, however the actual "checkbox" is not displaying on the front end of the website. It does however display on the back end of the website when I set-up the forms.

Can this possibly be a "conflict" with the Wordpress theme I'm using?

I've tried two different CCS Styling codes, however both were not working.

Do you have the same problem? If so, kindly advise if you have found a solution?

Here's a link of one of the forms, that I'm referring to:

https://naptosa.org.za/gauteng-application-form/

Thanking you in advance!

My best,
J

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the opacity of your checkboxes are set to 0 here:
https://naptosa.org.za/wp-content/cache/wpo-minify/1673584766/assets/wpo-minify-header-5bd14718.min.css

change the opacity by adding:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
    opacity: 1;
}
```